# How do I take data from a CSV file an insert it into a database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to insert data from a CSV file into an Oracle database.

I'm not sure where my problem is since it just keeps on looping.

My code so far:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args){

    if(args.length == 0){
      System.out.println("Error: No input");
      return;
    }

    String filePath = args[0];
    String line = "";

    String sql = "insert into leka_products(product_id, product_name, product_price) values (?,?,?)";

    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        PreparedStatement prepStat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))){

      Driver jdbcDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
      DriverManager.registerDriver(jdbcDriver);

      String[] products = null;

      while((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        products = line.split(",");

        int first = Integer.parseInt(products[0]);
        String second = products[1];
        Double third = Double.parseDouble(products[2]);

        prepStat.setInt(1, first);
        prepStat.setString(2, second);
        prepStat.setDouble(3, third);

        prepStat.executeUpdate();
      }

      System.out.println("Done!");

    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

This code, as it is, doesn't even finish. It just loops.

Is this approach even a correct one?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about *This code doesn't finish, it just loops* ? i don't get it. is it ok or do you expect something else?

Comment: Maybe you can try with SQL*Loader instead of java: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm

Comment: maybe you forgot to conn.commit() in the end.

Comment: Debug the code - see if the values are progressing, one iteration at a time. The database may require con.commit() to show the values, but if the loop doesn't exit it may mean that the file line isn't progressing.It's hard to believe considering this is what BufferedReader is meant to do and used for all the time.

Comment: @Assafs At "prepStat.executeUpdate();" it stays at "stepping". The rest seems to go through just fine, at least from what I see when debugging.

Comment: @HeartCore, if it says it's stepping, check if you have a breakpoint waiting. It may just be paused on a breakpoint in some thread. If this is the case, it would explain why you code doesn't reach the end - it just waits for you to review the breakpoint. Try to re-run the app without any breakpoints.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726978/how-to-insert-values-from-csv-into-database-in-java

Comment: @Assafs If I remove the breakpoints, it acts as if the program is run normally and keeps looping.

Comment: @HeartCore if you can’t safely debug, add printouts of each row it passes. You need to see when it’s running which line causes the loop.

Comment: @Assafs Did that. It passes every single line (and prints the test line) except for the "prepStat.executeUpdate()".

Comment: @HeartCore so it does one loop iteration, goes to the executeUpdate line and hangs there? It could be a DB time-out issue. Check if you have the DB configuration correctly.

Comment: @Assafs Everything worked fine all the time... I just left SQL Developer open. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you very much for your help!